# How to reload service configuration (php-fpm) inside a docker container?

Tags: php, docker

I need to run php-fpm with root user.

I'm following steps on this page [Start PHP-FPM with root option automatically](https://serverfault.com/a/789039/479680) but it looks like systemd and systemctl are not inluded in my baseimage ubuntu:16.04 then I can't reload service configuration.

Then how to proceed else ? Today, i'm installing apache/php-fpm in the same container.

Thanks in advance.

Dockerfile :

```html
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Installer Nano / Apache2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apt-utils \
    nano \
    apache2

# Activer le module Apache mod_proxy_fcgi
RUN a2enmod proxy_fcgi

# Activer le module Apache mod_rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Installation PHP + extensions / composer
RUN apt-get install -y \
    php-fpm \
    php-mcrypt \
    php-mysql \
    php-apcu \
    php-curl \
    php-intl \
    php-xdebug \
    php-xml \
    php-zip \
    php-bcmath \
    php-gd \
    php-json \
    php-ldap \
    php-mbstring \
    php-mysql \
    php-pgsql \
    php-sqlite3 \
    php-xml \
    php-xsl \
    php-zip \
    php-soap \
    php-opcache \
    composer

# Creation dossier php pour pid/socket php-fpm
RUN mkdir /run/php

# Activer config
RUN a2enconf php7.0-fpm

EXPOSE 80

VOLUME /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean
```

My docker-compose file :

```html
version: '2'

services:
    apachephp:
        container_name: monserveur
        image: toto/apache2_php-fpm7.0.30:0.4
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - D:\projets\lab.magento225:/var/www/html
        links:
            - db:db
        tty: true
    db:
        container_name: mabdd
        image: mysql:5.6
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - D:\local.databases\lab.magento225:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    pma:
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        links:
            - db:db
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way, that works in any Docker-based environment, is to stop and delete the container and run a new one, and it will read its new configuration on startup.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've done changes (edit /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf and /lib/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service) in the running container.Do you mean to commit the container (and then create a new image with changes) before to stop and delete, and run a new one, isn't it ?

Comment: I mean edit your `Dockerfile`, re-run `docker build`, and start a new container from the rebuilt image.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the help. Stop/delete container has not fixed the issue. As nothing was done with the dockerfile, I had to run service manually when I was creating a new container. Then I run php-fpm with root options and it has worked.

Comment: Try `docker compose up -d --build --remove-orphans`